# Are my S3 objects encrypted at rest or not?

Tags: encryption, amazon-s3

I have specified the following bucket policy to enforce encryption on PUT:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PutObjPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::com.my.bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "aws:kms"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**AND**

The properties of uploaded bucket objects indicate that they are encrypted

[image: image properties indicate encrypted]

**HOWEVER**

My "bucket properties" indicates that I'm NOT using default encryption:

[image: bucket encryption settings]

and I'm able to download these "encrypted" images from the console and view them locally after download, which I would hope was not possible if they're really encrypted.

So...have I achieved "encryption at rest" or not?

Comment: It's possible to have encryption enabled or disabled in 3 ways (1) as a bucket policy [affecting future files], (2) on an individual file base, (3) in bulk on past files.  In your screenshot, the bucket does not have a default encryption policy but the individual file is encrypted at rest. - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucket-encryption.html

Comment: Does this qualify as legally "encrypted at rest?" Basically if someone hacks the underlying infrastructure of AWS S3 and finds the files they will be encrypted but if they hack your S3 account its basically unencrypted on download, practically "stored" unencrypted. To be honest if someone was able to hack the S3 underlying servers decrypting is probably the easy job lol.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As your uploaded object shows the encryption as aws-kms, it means its clearly encrypted at rest. You do a upload directly from s3 UI, by default the encryption is none. after upload you will see the encryption is none. Encryption at rest means , your data is stored in the encrypted form on s3 disk/storage infrastructure.  However, it doesn't mean it will show on UI/or after download in encrypted format. When you download through sdk, it automatically decrypt the data. you always get decrypted data. Similarly the s3 UI show the decrypted content. What you want to achieve is client side encryption. Server side encryption is encryption at rest. When you do client side encryption data goes to s3 in encrypted format. Again when you download, its the client which has to decrypt the data.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingEncryption.html

Note : The term 'rest' means when data is resting (not in transition-while data is travelling to s3).
Server side encryption - this facilitates encryption at rest.

Client side encryption - this  facilitates encryption both in transition and at rest.

Encryption in transition alone can also be achieved by using ssl.